# why we need to use services and factories in this program?

Tags: angularjs

This is the program for find the square of a number in angularjs.here using services and factories.why we use both here or why we need to use services and factories in this program??

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.factory('MathService', function() {
        var factory = {}; 
        factory.multiply = function(a, b) {
             return a * b
        }
        return factory;
    });

    mainApp.service('CalcService', function(MathService){
        this.square = function(a) {
            return MathService.multiply(a,a);
         }
   });

     mainApp.controller('CalcController', function($scope, CalcService) {
           $scope.square = function() {
                $scope.result = CalcService.square($scope.number);
           }
```

Comment: Its up to you whether you want that code in a service or factory or normal JS function or Angular function. Depends on your requirements. Services are mostly use to make backend server calls though.

Comment: Service and factories are used to share code between controllers it up to your application if your controller needs some shared data then use them otherwise ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this explanation helps

First, right off the bat I’ll say they’re pretty much equivalent. Why do we have them both, then? That’s for the gods of Angular to know. They both allow us to create an object that can then be used anywhere in our app.

Most important is to realize that both are singletons in your app, even though the name “factory” might imply differently.

Essentially, factories are functions that return the object, while services are constructor functions of the object which are instantiated with the new keyword.

```
angular.module('app').controller('TheCtrl', function($scope, SomeService) {
SomeService.someFunction();
});
Here is a matching factory:

angular.module('app').factory('SomeService', function() {
return {
  someFunction: function() {}
      };
});
```

Ref:http://www.codelord.net/2015/04/28/angularjs-whats-the-difference-between-factory-and-service/